# Can i run Android Studio 3.2 (latest version) properly on 2GB RAM?

Tags: android-studio

I really want to run the latest version of Android Studio, but i have only 2GB of RAM. Can I run it properly, including SDK?

[image: Here is a image about my computer(click here)]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Android Developers main page](https://developer.android.com/studio/), in the System Requirements section:

> 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android
>   Emulator